# Где находится окно Resources в Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Имеется задание - В следующем окне (рис. 2.46) выбираем ресурс project/default_text_size (относится к компоненту textview). Подскажите как открыть это окно Resources?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Рисунок 2.46

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То что передо мной